# Bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive asks for a username and a password

Tags: password, username

I just created a bootable Ubuntu 15.10 USB flash drive. On start-up, it asks for a user name and a password. Which user name and password am I supposed to enter here?

Answer (score 0):

The following may work: username = 'ubuntu', and the password is blank